# Unzip Multiple files containing same name using R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, unzip

I have a 105 zipped files in a folder. They all contain one csv file each with the same name i.e. 'EapTransactions_1'

Currently I am using the following code in R to extract all of them into a new folder :

```
library(plyr)    
outDir<-"C:/Users/dhritul.gupta/Migration Files/Trial1/extract"
zipF=list.files(path = "C:/Users/dhritul.gupta/Migration Files/Trial1", pattern = "*.zip", full.names = TRUE)
ldply(.data = zipF, .fun = unzip, exdir = outDir)
```

The problem with this approach is that since all file names are the same every one of them get overwritten and only the last one is saved.

Is there anyway to save each one of them by renaming them or adding a prefix/suffix to the file names while extraction?

Comment: a similar solution using `purrr` instead of deprecated `plyr` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217569/r-unzip-several-files-each-in-new-subdirectory-or-rename/

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `file.rename` to add a unique number to the end of each file, before you make the call which uses `unzip`:

```
zipF <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/dhritul.gupta/Migration Files/Trial1",
    pattern = "*.zip", full.names = TRUE)
file.rename(zipF, paste0("EapTransactions_", 1:105))
ldply(.data=zipF, .fun=unzip, exdir=outDir)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error - Error in file.rename(zipF, paste0("EapTransactions_", 1:105)) : 
  'from' and 'to' are of different lengths

Comment: `I have a 105 zipped files in a folder` ... it looks like you don't, but we can fix the above code if you tell us how many files you actually do have.

Comment: Translation: The error message is saying that you _don't_ have 105 files in the folder, but rather you have some other number.  Please tell us how many files you actually have.

Comment: you are right. I am so sorry but there were only 104 files in the folder. But when i changed the code i got the following error in the next line : > ldply(.data = zipF, .fun = unzip, exdir = outDir)
Error in quickdf(unname(split(vec, rep(seq_len(ncol), nrow)))) : 
  length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: I don't know why you are getting this error.  Check to make sure that the files actually exist.  Maybe try to get it to work with just one ZIP file, then build up from there.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build something based on Tim's idea. It worked for me when I stored the files at a temporary location to rename the files. I then moved the renamed files to the final destination and deleted the temporary files.

```
TempoutDir <-"C:/Users/dhritul.gupta/Migration Files/Trial1/extract/Temp" # Define a temp location

setwd(TempoutDir) #setwd for rename/remove functions to work

for (i in 1:length(zipF))
{
  unzip(zipF[i],exdir=TempoutDir,overwrite = FALSE)  

  #Files are overwritten because of same name. Give a new name to the file with a random number using runif and save them at the final location. Delete the files in temp folder

  a <- c(list.files(TempoutDir)) #Vector with actual file name

  b <- c(paste(runif(length(list.files(TempoutDir)), min=0, max=1000 ),as.character(list.files(TempoutDir))))
  #Vector with an appended temp number in front of the file name

  file.rename(a,b) # Rename the file in temp location
  file.copy(list.files(TempoutDir),outDir) # Move file from temp location to main location
  file.remove(list.files(TempoutDir)) # Delete files in Temp location
  rm(a)
  rm(b) #Delete vectors a,b from environment

}
```

You should have all the files moved to the desired folder with random numbers appended in front of the file names and nothing left in the temp folder