# R: Unzip several files, each in new subdirectory or rename

Tags: r, unzip

I managed to adapt some code to unzip many files.
However, when unzipping, files with the same name appear to
be replaced.

In my working directory, I have .zip files.
I created a new folder in that directory called unzip,
in which I unzipped the files.

`dir.create(paste0(path, "/unzip/"))`

`ldply(.data = list.files(path = path, pattern = ".zip", full.names = T), .fun = unzip, exdir = paste0(path, "/unzip"), overwrite = FALSE)`

As each of the .zip file has the same architecture, files will get replaced. My question: 
1) Is there a way to specify that each file should be renamed if double?
2) Other way round would be to specify that in the unzip folder, for each .zip file, a new folder would be created in which the corresponding file is unzipped.

THX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `plyr` package is deprecated, I will be using `purrr::walk()` instead. I'm loading the entire `tidyverse` since `stringr::str_c()` is also used. In the following code, `"zip_files"`is the directory containing the zip-files and `"zip_out"` is the folder where the files are extracted to, both being in the working directory. The latter contains a folder for each zip file. Folders do not need to be created beforehand, as `unzip()` takes care of that for us.

```r
library(tidyverse)

file_names <- list.files("zip_files")
walk(file_names, ~ unzip(zipfile = str_c("zip_files/", .x), 
                         exdir = str_c("zip_out/", .x)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Indeed ```walk()``` is very convenient in this case! Thanks for opening my eyes!